# GNU Inline assembly problem

Tags: c++, c, gnu, inline-assembly

I did some refactoring at [c167](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C167_family) platform specific code and I stumbled upon an inline assembly problem.

Previous code:

```
  asm volatile ( "
            extp   #pag:%0, #3
            mov    r4, pof:%0   @ R4 = g_nRcvBufCount
            sub    r4, #1       @ R4 = R4 - 1
            mov    pof:%0, r4   @ g_nRcvBufCount = R4"
        : "=m" (g_nRcvBufCount)
        :
        : "r4"
  );
```

[

Basically this code does an atomic decrement of "g_nRcvBufCount" variable

"extp" instruction takes the "page" of the "g_nRcvBufCount" variable and the number of atomic expressions that follow (3 in this case)

]

Current - not compiling code:

```
  asm volatile ( "
            extp   #pag:%0, #3
            mov    r4, pof:%0   @ R4 = cfg->g_nRcvBufCount
            sub    r4, #1       @ R4 = R4 - 1
            mov    pof:%0, r4   @ cfg->g_nRcvBufCount = R4"
        : "=m" (cfg->g_nRcvBufCount)
        :
        : "r4"
  );
```

where cfg is a pointer to a structure containing the "g_nRcvBufCount" variable.

```
struct {
  ...
  unsigned short g_nRcvBufCount;
  ...
}cfg;
```

The errors received in compilation are:

```
test.c:1124:Warning:Missing operand value assumed absolute 0. 
test.c:1124:extp #pag:[r2+#66],#3: trailing chars after expression    
test.c:1125:Warning:Missing operand value assumed absolute 0. 
test.c:1125:mov r4,pof:[r2+#66]: trailing chars after expression   
test.c:1127:Warning:Missing operand value assumed absolute 0. 
test.c:1127:mov pof:[r2+#66],r4: trailing chars after expression
```

Any hints about how to make this work are welcome. Also an x86 version (of inline assembly) on how to access variables defined in a C/C++ structure would be helpful. Documentation of the GNU inline assembler explaining what "=m" keyword does is also useful.

Thanks in advance,

Iulian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the asm in the warning message:

```
extp #pag:[r2+#66],#3
```

Apparently the `#pag:` thing is valid with a register or absolute address after it, but not with a more complex expression already containing an offset like `[r2+#66]`. You might need to switch to using a `"r"` argument containing the *address of* `cfg->g_nRcvBufCount` instead of a `"m"` argument referencing it.

If this is the case, note that the original code was *bogus* to begin with, and only happened to work because gcc decided to substitute a simple address expression that worked in the asm.

Answer (score 1):

from [ibiblio](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

"m" : A memory operand is allowed, with any kind of address that the machine supports in general.

about "errors" - these are "only" warnings - try to make a small .c file with this assembly and disassemble it and look how objdump outputs it. it might give you clue on how edit your code to not have these warnings